# FireStore read fails silently and I have no idea why

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Help is much appreciated how to trace down this issue, because I am running out of ideas.

I am calling the function getOrderCollection, below, but it aborts after the first line `var myCompanyDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('companies').doc(myCompany).get();` Without trowing anything to the console or jumping into some library when debugging. When I click next statement it jumps back to the calling function.

I am authenticated to the database, `companyCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('companies')` provides an initialized object pointing to the collection and myCompany is a constant with the document id entered by copy/paste.

If some rules for the database but I can't see successful or denied queries with the monitor.

Any ideas how I can proceed tracing down the issue?

```dart
  Future<void> getOrderCollection() async {
    var myCompanyDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('companies').doc(myCompany).get();
    print("companyDoc fetched");
    final myDeliveryDocRef = myCompanyDoc.data()['delivery'].toString();
    orderCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('companies').doc(myCompany).collection('features').doc(myDeliveryDocRef).collection('orders');
    orderBriefDoc = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('companies').doc(myCompany).collection('features').doc(myDeliveryDocRef);
  }
```

UPDATE: This is collection > document what corresponds to `final String myCompany = '4U4kZKXkr3rHA6B04S5K';`

[image]

Comment: What does your collection look like in the Firebase? Maybe, the doc is missing. You are using `myCompany` variable to access the doc. Are you sure that the document is present? A screenshot might be useful.

Also, sometimes wrapping with try...catch clause might help identify the exact issue.

In fact, since your method `getOrderCollection()` is async, you need to make sure the caller awaits that method. Have you done that?

Comment: I have added the screenshot of firebase. Besides using `await _deliveryRepository.initRepository();` when calling `getOderCollection()`, the function though being async should still call the print and the following of its statements, but it is not.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot provided. So from what you said, you don't `await` the `getOrderCollection()` function, right? What happens if you `await` it? That's the reason why it jumps to another library because it does multiple things at the same time. If you `await` it, the execution will go line by line.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comments. No, I do wait for the function (`await _deliveryRepository.initRepository();`). But even if I wouldn't, I believe all lines of the functions should be executed. I just added try catch (good point), but it does not catch anything, the catching statement is not executed.

Comment: what you are saying is that you await `_deliveryRepository.initRepository();` but you didn't say you await `getOderCollection()`. Where do you call the `getOrderCollection()` method? Could you attach the code you are using? You should have a line `await getOderCollection();` and not just `getOderCollection();` where you call it. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: This definitely makes sense. And you are absolutely right, I forgot await in the function initRepository() which  is calling getOrderCollection. Though I do not understand why this causes getOrderCollection not to execute the succeeding line. Whatsoever, this issue is gone, and I am stuck with the next one :-) Happy to accept your comments as an answer

Comment: I am happy that helped. If you need additional help, feel free to ask a new question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in your comments, the issue was that you forgot to `await` the `getOrderCollection()` function. Even though, as you mentioned, your caller function `_deliveryRepository.initRepository()` was awaited, you still had to `await getOrderCollection()` inside your caller method to make sure that the code is waiting for the `getOrderCollection()` to be executed before it proceeds to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want to have some error handling and to type the known types/classes (**avoid using `var`**).

- Error handling - for `async/await` place the code inside a `try/catch`.
- Typing - [Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system) is type safe, which is really great to prevent runtime errors.

Depending on your setup, you might be able to hover over the `Firestore.instance.collection(...).doc(...)` to see the return type. `.doc(...).get()` returns a `DocumentSnapshot` and `.collection(...).get()` returns a `CollectionSnapshot`.

Using the above, it should be easier to debug:

```
 Future<void> getOrderCollection() async {
   try {
     DocumentSnapshot myCompanyDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('companies').doc(myCompany).get();
     print("companyDoc fetched");
     final myDeliveryDocRef = myCompanyDoc.data()['delivery'].toString();

   } catch(e) {
     print('Error: ' + e.toString());
   }
 }
```

Don't forget to `await` your other 2 Firestore queries.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I should have used try / catch. But as I wrote in the comment above, no exception was thrown by this line, so I could not catch anything after adding this. The issue was a missing await - apologies. Anyways, thank you for your contribution